# Postgresql sorting language specific characters (collation)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, collation

I, as a speaker of language, which has several non-common characters like ÕÜÖÄ, think that if i create an app, which allows user to save content in estonian to database, then this app should also be able to sort data correctly according to language settings.

Also, as a spear of very small language, like estonian is, have to consider, that other people might use the app and want sorting in their language. Several european languages also have their own mix of special characters.

Its even worse, if you include languages like russian into the mix - they have completely different characters.

Now since i know the django site can display all those special characters just fine, i'm only worried about sorting, which goes on database level. So how can i ensure, that objects are read from database and sorted into correct, language specific order.

Example case:
If i create database with utf8 encoding and with default collation(english utf8), then table containing values

```
alan
oskar
ölen
älan
öskar
```

Will be sorted (by "select * from test order by nimi asc;") to:

```
alan
älan
ölen
oskar
öskar
```

Which is incorrect. If i create database with POSIX collation, then same query results in:

```
alan
oskar
älan
ölen
öskar
```

This SEEMS to be correct, cause if you throw few more names (õlan, ålan) into the mix, then the results are:

```
alan
oskar
älan
ålan
õlan
ölen
öskar
```

Cause, according to estonian alphabet, they should be:

```
alan
oskar
õlan
älan
ölen
öskar
ålan (cause å is not in estonian alphabet)
```

I am using postgresql 9.1.9 and i understand that collation support is available since 9.1 (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/collation.html).

Is that what i should use?

```
SELECT nimi COLLATE "et_EE" FROM test ORDER BY nimi ASC;
```

Fails with error ERROR:  collation "et_EE.utf8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist. Why is that? 
Do i have to create this collation rule or something? 
Is this the way to go - to specify collation rule with every query, if i want results in correct order?

Alan

Edit :1 to answer question:
my locale -a shows:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
et_EE
et_EE.iso88591
et_EE.utf8
POSIX
zh_CN.utf8
zh_SG.utf8

sudo locale-gen et_EE.UTF-8
[sudo] password for alan: 
Generating locales...
  et_EE.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
sudo locale-gen et_EE
Generating locales...
  et_EE.ISO-8859-1... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

SQL still fails though

Edit2: I think i figured it out. I had to create the collation itself in postgresql too (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createcollation.html):

```
CREATE COLLATION "et_EE" (LOCALE = "et_EE.utf8")
```

So i guess i have to create those shell locale files, that you told me about, zero323, and then create collations to database and then i'm all set.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: By the way, in Portuguese `àáãâä` come after `a` and before `b`, because characters with accents are ordered next to the same character without accent. So for `pt-PT` I would expect it to order `alan
älan
oskar
ölen
öskar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check installed locale using:

```
locale -a
```

If et_EE is not listed run this commands:

```
sudo locale-gen et_EE
sudo locale-gen et_EE.UTF-8
sudo update-locale
```

and try your query again.

Comment: Thanks. et_EE is listed now, but nothing changed for any of the queries

Comment: Yup. i ran sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart and tried "SELECT nimi COLLATE "et_EE" FROM test ORDER BY nimi ASC;" again. And it failed

Comment: That's weird. I performed all the steps on clean vm and everything seems to work. Do you `et_EE` (without UTF_8) in `locale -a` output? If not try `sudo locale-gen et_EE` and repeating other steps.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb you should post that edit as an answer, and not leave it as an edit at the end of the question.