# Django making a query with custom collation

Tags: django, collation

Is it possible to make query with a collation different from database table have?

Comment: Do you want use your django model on an existing database with a different collation or do you want a query beyond django's model framework?

Comment: Hmmm, using with a different collation seems work fine but maybe in future i would need to make query with collation database have.
i prefer to use different collation just with that query if it is possible.

with 'beyond django's model framework' do you mean raw sql query?

Comment: yeah, if you want to work with a database which is not affiliated to django's databases.

Comment: No no, it is the database django created if i you mean that?

Comment: Okay, when Django's is the creator of the database, why do you need a different collation?

Comment: i have a column called `name` which is unique. in my language character `ö` differ to `o` so it changed to a different collation from `utf8_general_ci`. But know i want to make search query with `ö` and `o` as same.

Comment: This is a different question, isn't it? :)

Comment: why? i want make a query with a collation `utf8_general_ci` which database column collation is different. You mean i need to solve this problem in a different way from a custom collation query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can use a specific collation instead of the default collation for a given table/column.  I'm assuming you always want that to be the case insensitive utf8_general_ci, but you can easily change that in the code or add it as a variable.

Note the use of the params kwarg instead of the db literal function.  Params exists for the exact same purpose.

```
def iexact(**kw):
    fields = [['%s=%%s collate utf8_general_ci'%field,value] for (field,value) in kw.items()]
    return dict(where=[f[0] for f in fields], params=[f[1] for f in fields])

if User.objects.extra(**iexact(username='joeblow')).exists():
    status = "Found a user with this username!"
```

Comment: Ohh, When you focus on something, you don't think of other options. I read django `where` usage documentation nearly 3 times but I couldn't realize this, that is embarrassing :)
This is the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 13):

Using `extra()` is a little messy. Something similar can now be achieved with [Func()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) expression (since Django 1.8):

```
username_ci = Func(
    'username',
    function='utf8_general_ci',
    template='(%(expressions)s) COLLATE "%(function)s"')
```

This can be used in `annotate()`:

```
User.objects.annotate(uname_ci=username_ci).filter(uname_ci='joeblow').exists()
```

Or in `order_by()` to override default collation rules when sorting:

```
User.objects.order_by(username_ci)
```

Now, it still may seem messy, but if you look at the docs and code of [Func()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions), you will discover that it is very easy to subclass it and make a reusable collation setter.

I used this trick with Postgres database.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this using bit of a hack;

Django's `extra` method is just like `raw` method, they both using the query statetment directly;

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=["name LIKE '%%" + name + "%%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci"])
```

But like this sql injection is possible. We need to escape `name` variable. I searched a lot for a function which just escapes a string for db. Found one in `MySQL-python` package but it can't escape unicode strings. Also package has `literal` method in `connection` but to use it we need an instance (maybe it is for db characteristic).

At last I used Django's `db.connection.cursor`.

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
name = cursor.db.connection.literal(name)[1:-1]  # [1:-1] excluding quotes
```

With this way we also need an instance but I suppose this not require a db connection. And I suppose this method db independent. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: **FYI**: using `.extra()` with parameters this way is _unsafe_! 

more on that topic: https://blog.r2c.dev/2020/preventing-sql-injection-a-django-authors-perspective/

Answer (score 1):

This above solution works. In case of getting the reverse order the following snippet

```py
sort_value = sort.strip()
if sort_value in ['name', '-name']:
    sort = Func('name', function='C', template='(%(expressions)s) COLLATE "%(function)s"')
if sort_value in ['-name']:
    f_res = queryset.order_by(sort).reverse()
else:
    f_res = queryset.order_by(sort)
return f_res
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come here with almost the same problem. The docs say the devs very much want to deprecate extra(). And I've ended up with this:

```
from django.db import models
queryset.filter(name__icontains=models.functions.Collate(models.Value(search_term), 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'))
```