# django extend query condition `COLLATION`

Tags: mysql, django, collation

django==1.11.9

mysql version 5.6.38

```
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

I have an accent field in my data, and I set the unique field. However, multiple results will appear in the query. Although I know you can by `ALTER TABLE test DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_bin;` set the table properties. But I think the better way is through the query to add conditions `SELECT * FROM test WHERE name = 'a' collate utf8_bin;`.

Now I don't know how to use it in the queryset method. When I was in inserting data usually use `update_or_create()` method, which will directly lead to some other form (with accent) data is not inserted into it.

Can this query condition be extended in Django's queryset method?

Comment: I think this will require a `raw` query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841132/django-making-a-query-with-custom-collation maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE test DEFAULT COLLATE ...` only changes the "default".  That is, when you *later* add a column, it will get that collation.

Instead:

`ALTER TABLE test MODIFY xyz ... COLLATE ...` for each column you need to change.

Or you could blindly change all the varchar/text columns:

`ALTER TABLE test CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET ... COLLATE ...;

Note that no index can be used when you have `WHERE name = 'a' COLLATE ...` -- It will have to check all rows even if you have `INDEX(name)`.

`..._bin` collations check the bits; that is, they are case and accent sensitive sensitive.  `..._ci` collations are case and accent insensitive.

I would put the collation in the `WHERE` clause *only* when you need to vary the collation.  Otherwise, build it into the column definition.