# In Django with Postgresql 9.6 how to sort case and accent insensitive?

Tags: django, postgresql, sorting

What I would like is the equivalent of using `utf8_unicode_ci` in MySQL. So if I have those strings (default sort order with Postgresql):

- Barn
- Bubble
- Bœuf
- beef
- boulette
- bémol

I wish they would be sorted like this (as with `utf8_unicode_ci` in MySQL):

- Barn
- beef
- bémol
- Bœuf
- boulette
- Bubble

This kind of sort is case insensitive, accent insensitive and ligatures are converted to multiple characters.

I know about `unaccent` and `lower` in Postgresql but I have no idea how to use them from Django.

Possible solutions with Django/Postgresql:

- Add new column only for sorting with data normalized (lower, unaccent).
- Add an index ([like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216)), but I'm not sure how it will work with Django?

I don't think Full Text Search or Trigram could help me here because I'm not necessarily doing searches base on text but I need to get the good sort order.

Ideally queries should be fast so using another indexed column looks like a good avenue. But I wish to find a solution that I don't need to implement for every exisiting text column in my DB, that is easy to maintain, etc. Is there a best practice to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't related to Django itself, PostgreSQL's `lc_collate` configuration determines this. I'd suggest you to review its value:

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

The right thing to do is fix this configuration. Don't forget to take a look on related settings too (`lc_ctype`, etc.).

But if you cannot create another database with the right setting, try to explicit `collate` on `ORDER` like the following test case:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table1 (column1 TEXT); 

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('Barn'),
('beef'),
('bémol'),
('Bœuf'),
('boulette'),
('Bubble');

SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY column1 COLLATE "en_US"; --Gives the expected order
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY column1 COLLATE "C"; --Gives "wrong" order  (in your case)
```

It's important to remember that PostgreSQL relies on operating system locales. This test case was executed on CentOS 7. More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36423340/7925366).

Comment: To my knowledge, Postgresql do not have any collation that will do the kind of sort I want. If you could prove me wrong I'll be happy!

Comment: @Etienne I added a test case to my answer.

Comment: I tried your test case and both `SELECT` gives the same sort order. But I'm on an old OS X system and reading your message it remember me that I probably had this problem on this system a few years ago! I will test it on another system and come back. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, my problem is bad system's locales on my old OS X system. It's really time to upgrade this system! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help you @Etienne

Answer (score 0):

I did this way:

But you need enable in your postgresql the module '**unaccent**' before this way:
    `CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;`

```
def get_value_ci(field):
    return Func(field, function='LOWER', template='UNACCENT(%(function)s(%(expressions)s))')

YoutModel.objects.order_by(get_value_ci('nome_your_field'))
```

and works, ;)