# utf8_lithuanian_ci doesn't help to match unicode characters

Tags: mysql, django, collation

Lithuanian language has some specific letters: `ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽąčęėįšųūž`. I would like to search in queryset in Django admin changelist so that a string `aceeisuuz` would match `ąčęėįšųūž`.

I think django has nothing to do with it, but just in case I have mentioned it. By the way, database backend - MySQL.

I have set `utf8_lithuanian_ci` collation on the columns I am searching in, but matching does not work for some letters.

a -> ą MATCHES

c -> č DOESN'T MATCH

e -> ę MATCHES

e -> ė MATCHES

i -> į MATCHES

s -> š DOESN'T MATCH

u -> ų MATCHES

u -> ū MATCHES

z -> ž DOESN'T MATCH

What am I missing?

Comment: You probably have the same problem that i had. Check out this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932922/postgresql-sorting-language-specific-characters-collation. You are using mysql though, so i have no idea if it's the same problem. But matching o to ö was part of my problem too.